# How do I upload data and display it on another page?

Tags: php, select

I basically have two php pages, one is *uploadnotif.php* and another is *notif.php*.

What these pages are supposed to do is that when admin types some notice on uploadnotif.php and uploads it, the other people can view them on notif.php.

And all this is according to a select option which has suppose

- ALL
- XYZ
- ABC

If admin selects ALL on uploadnotif.php and uploads it, then the content can be viewed using ALL dropdown on notif.php and same for XYZ and ABC.

**Example:**

Option selected XYZ

Notice typed, Hello World! and then Uploaded.

So the user when selects XYZ can see "Hello World!" as one of the notices and so on will be the notices lined according to the order they are uploaded in.

I am really confused regarding how exactly should I proceed with it? Should I use file or should I use a database or any other method? And how should I use it?

Please help!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In uploadnotif.php ,when the option is selected then a post request using ajax for that option can be sent.For example if you select abc,use jquery to get the option selected and then send data with abc as the paramter.

In notif.php check if the paramter for the corresponding option is set and then display the data recieved

Comment: Hello @anoop , I am planning to use tables because I want to store the notifications. Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to persist these notifications so that you can present them to users later on. You could use a database to store the admin's notifications.

1. Save the input from the uploadnotif.php form to a `notifications` table with columns notification and option.
2. Retrieve data from the notifications table and present it however you need to in notif.php.

Edit: To present the notifications in the order they were added, you could use a column like date_added or upload_time. Then you could sort by date when you retrieve the data.

N.B, think about sanitising input when processing form data.

Comment: Hey! @hassan Thanks a lot for your response. This is pretty much clear now. I will try this and get back to you if I need help. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Hey @LazyNinja, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this from scratch, so there's prolly lots of errors but you should get the idea, even if you don't use MySQL. The basic idea is the admin uploads the message along with the type via AJAX to the server. The database storing your messages is updated. When users select a type on their notification page, another AJAX request is made to retrieve the proper message, which gets displayed however you want. If you need clarification on anything, let me know.

**In uploadnotif.php:**

```
<input id="message_to_broadcast" type="text">

<select id="message_type">
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
  <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
</select>

<div id="broadcast" onclick="OnBroadcast();">Broadcast</div>

<script>

OnBroadcast = function()
{
    var oMessageInput = document.getElementById("message_to_broadcast");
    var oTypeSelect = document.getElementById("message_type");

    var aPostData = "message=" + oMessageInput.value + "&type=" + oTypeSelect.value;

    var oXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "broadcast_message.php", true);
    oXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    oXMLHttpRequest.send(aPostData);
}

</script>
```

**In broadcast_message.php:**

```
$safe_message = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["message"]);
$safe_type = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["type"]);

$query = "UPDATE messages SET message = $safe_message WHERE type = $safe_type";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

**In notif.php:**

```
<div id="message">&nbsp;</div>

<select id="message_type" onchange="OnMessageTypeChange();">
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
  <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
</select>

<script>

OnMessageTypeChange = function()
{
    var oTypeSelect = document.getElementById("message_type");

    var aPostData = "type=" + oTypeSelect.value;

    var oXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "get_message.php", true);
    oXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    oXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (oXMLHttpRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && oXMLHttpRequest.status == 200)
        {
            var oMessageDiv = document.getElementById("message");
            oMessageDiv.firstChild.nodeValue = oXMLHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    oXMLHttpRequest.send(aPostData);
}

</script>
```

**In get_message.php:**

```
$safe_type = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["type"]);

$query = "SELECT message FROM messages WHERE type = $safe_type";
$message_result = $mysqli->query($query);
$message_assoc = $message_result->fetch_assoc();

echo $message_assoc["message"];

$message_result->free();
```

**"messages" table:**

```
id |  type | message 

 1 | "ALL" | "All y'all call Paul a tall wall."
 2 | "ABC" | "ABC members, meeting at noon tomorrow."
 3 | "XYZ" | "XYZ! What up party people!"
```

Comment: hello @DaiBu , Thanks a lot for your response. I am actually unfamiliar with AJAX. I am able to understand the basic idea of what you just explain but if possible is there any other way to do it? Also can you tell me what all tables and columns will I need to create before implementing this code?

Comment: Sure. I don't have time right now, but I'll edit my answer tonight.

Comment: Sure Sure. No problem. Take your time. And again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Another possibility is form submission, but that will not look nearly as clean. My suggestion is learn AJAX. I mean, the code I wrote is 90% of everything there is too it. I think if you copy and paste my code and play around with it while reading a tutorial, you can get the gist of it in an hour. Now I'll update my post with the table creation info (there's only one small one).

Comment: Hey @Daibu Thanks a lot. I guess I will proceed as per your guidance. Thanks again.

Comment: Also can you tell me how the various messages will be stored in the table?

Comment: It's at the bottom of my answer above. Just create a "type", "message" and optional "id" column.

Comment: Ya that I did see but what I wanted to ask was, how so many notices will be stored? @Daibu And also how to I interact with the database here? Like for login page I had used "require". What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Uh-oh. I think this might be out of your league until you learn more stuff. First of all, in my example, I was only storing three notices, one for each type (ALL, ABC and XYZ). But you can make it more complicated and store as many as you want of course. I think you don't understand this part... When you access a php file, it runs code on your server. Simply navigating to http://somewebaddress.com/somefile.php in a browser runs whatever code is inside somefile.php. When you access a php page with AJAX, it's like using require. Well, not really, but it runs the code inside of the file.

Comment: So above, you access get_message.php (with parameters) from Javascript using XMLHTTPRequest. The server says, "Hey, this IP address wants us to run get_message.php?type=XYZ." The server runs the php script. Inside it, there is code that accesses the database and echo's the result back to the IP address that made the call. Back in Javascript land, the client's computer receives the message and you can do what ever you want with it.

Comment: To clarify, this line:

oXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "broadcast_message.php", true);

...tells the admin's computer that the admin wants to store a new message (overwriting the old one of the same type).

Comment: This line:

var aPostData = "message=" + oMessageInput.value + "&type=" + oTypeSelect.value;

...combined with this one:

    oXMLHttpRequest.send(aPostData);

...adds parameters to the address and actually makes the request. Inside broadcast_message.php, you can access the variables by using $_POST["type"] or $_POST["message"].